# JSP session not using servlets

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

My problem is: I want to use sessions on my JSP pages, without using servlets (like php for example)

The problem is: how to do that? I read that session is implicite like request in jsp, but I don't actually know how to use it.

I've got a main page, who passes itself some variables on the url (like index.jsp?id=1).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:set>` and `<c:remove>` to manage session attributes.

The following does effectively a `session.setAttribute("foo", "bar")`:

```
<c:set var="foo" value="bar" scope="session" />
```

And the following does effectively a `session.removeAttribute("foo")`:

```
<c:remove var="foo" scope="session" />
```

Of course, you can use the usual EL way of accessing attributes, the following prints `session.getAttribute("foo")`.

```
${foo}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should work on your aversion against servlets. This is not a good practice. JSTL doesn't offer everything making business logic a breeze, which would force you to fall back to legacy *scriptlets*. I hope that it's just ignorance. Carefully read our servlets wiki page to learn how it can easily be created and used: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info Also this answer might be somewhat enlightening: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but the main problem is that I'm working on something not created by me: this mean that I've found this "mess", and I don't think I have enough time to renew it with a correct code. As I read on those links, you are REALLY right, so thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have two jsp

1. index.jsp =  get the parameter in index.jsp and add the value to session (implicit objects)

   `<%`
   `String empId = request.getParameter("id");

   session.setAttribute("empId", empId);

   response.sendRedirect("homePage.jsp");`

   `%>`
2. Now in homePage.jsp = Write code to retrieve the value previously added with key **empId**

   `<%`

   `String employeId = (String)session.getAttribute("empId");`

   `%>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wanted to work only on a single JSP page.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this in jsp code

```
       <%

     HttpSession sess = request.getSession();

     if (sess==null)
     {
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
         dispatcher.forward(request, response);                        
     }

      %>
```

you can get session and its attribute

and for index.jsp?id=1 you can use

```
         request.getParameter("id")
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't redirect to other JSP, I handle everything in my index.jsp page. I've tried to use before 'HttpSession sess = request.getSession();' but when i submit something, and the page reload itself, I get an error because there are multiple declaration of sess variable.

Comment: please check session object before creation if it is already exist then do not create otherwise create it simply